# how to extract phone/mobile number from a big string using regex in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, regex

I have a big string which looks something like shown below.
  i want to extract those 3 numbers which are in the string
   1.9886991201     2.+7189674123      3.(080)-2235456

```
$var = '

rst post. Edit or delete it, then start writing!

will change the whole world

Search for: 
Search …
RECENT POSTS

This is my first blog post
Hello world!
RECENT COMMENTS

Mr WordPress on Hello world!
ARCHIVES

August 2016
July 2016
CATEGORIES

Uncategorized
META

Log in
Entries RSS
Comments RSS
WordPress.org
Proudly powered by WordPress


dajsnjdgffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffz 
9886991201...dfsdsddfgf
ddffgbnfhgjhjgjg
dfknfkjkndfdjkfdjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj
mskjndkjdnndnjdfjjdm
njcddfdnfnzdfdzfdzfdj+7189674123msdfjgfdxfds
dwasnkbnznfvnndfv
aefnbhjmbffdsnfnndv
dmlnjdnvdnsnvdndv
dLKMNJFNNFVNFGN
DNBFDBFJFDJF
do code...
while (fsdkmnbv vx b  s
    fgzd zvn bmbfmbfxmbfxm);,dwdfen   (080)-2235456          ananczzzzzzzzzz bcxxx AS SNDMCKJASOL   P0-`0-1`1WE2IQ82EYQWASHBZXNdwhbjbjdhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhas
dmfndsvfncx 

';
```

Comment: please re-format your question and show the code what you tried so far.

Comment: preg_match_all("/((?:\d{3}[.-]|\(\d{3}\)\s+)\d{3}[.-]\d{4})(?:\s+Ext\.\s+(\d+)|\s+\(.*?\))?/Ux",$var,$mobile);
echo "<pre>";print_r($mobile[0]);die;

Comment: https://eval.in/619770

Comment: the above regex not returning anything, returning a null array

Comment: First you need the specific format for phone numbers (number of digits, prefixes) after that you can use preg_match or preg_match_all and a regex at your choice...

Comment: i want to extract those mobile numbers which is there inside the big string.

Comment: Try this: ([\(?]\d+[\)?].?\d{6,10})|(\+?\d{10,12})

Comment: You can set the number of digits according to your country, i have no idea how many digits tel numbers have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per your description, I see three different patterns of number that you want to search.

1. 10 digits
2. `+` sign followed by 10 digits
3. (xxx)-xxxxxxX format

This patterns can be matched using the following regex

```
/[\+]?\d{10}|\(\d{3}\)\s?-\d{6}/
```

https://regex101.com/r/dJ9cV2/5

https://regex101.com/r/dJ9cV2/6

https://regex101.com/r/dJ9cV2/7

Comment: 3360140 thats great but it is extracting only 988699121, could do it for all

Comment: thanks @user3360140, i have checked it and is working fine.